# Postgres large object does not exist error for an existing object

Tags: postgresql

I am getting an error with Postgres 10 when trying to delete a large object `ERROR:  large object 16709 does not exist` even though I can show `16709` *does* exist. I don't know if it is relevant, but the large object was created using `pyscopg2` on Python 3.

EDIT:
I confirmed that I can still fetch the data from the database, and that it is correct. I just can't delete it.

```
tagger1=# select l.oid from pg_largeobject_metadata l where l.oid = 16709;
  oid
-------
 16709
(1 row)

tagger1=# select count(1) from pg_largeobject where loid = 16709;
 count
-------
   747
(1 row)

tagger1=# select lo_unlink(16709) from pg_largeobject;
ERROR:  large object 16709 does not exist
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply omit the `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT lo_unlink(16709);
```

The problem is that your statement tries to run this for every row in `pg_largeobject`, but after the first execution the large object is already gone.

Comment: Thank you. Turns out in my program I was trying to `unlink()` twice using the `pyscopg2` object, and then I made this mistake when debugging interactively.